# Programmatically unchecking a Checkbox within Vaadin Context Menu

Tags: checkbox, vaadin, contextmenu, vaadin-flow

I've created a Context menu with a tree structure (added Menu items, then added Checkboxes within those menu items as sub-menu items). This works just fine in terms of adding/removing items manually. However, when it comes to programmatically resetting items there is a conflict in terms of a general Component vs. specific component (in this case, a Checkbox).

```
Component comp = contextMenu.getItems().get(x).getSubMenu().getItems().get(y);
if (comp instanceof Checkbox) {
    ((Checkbox) comp).setValue(false);
}
```

Note that comp is **not** in fact an instance of Checkbox; rather it is returning as com.vaadin.flow.component.contextmenu.MenuItem and that item cannot be cast to a Checkbox. So the question is, how would I uncheck a given Checkbox?

Comment: Have you tried `comp.getChildren()` to see if they contain the Checkboxes directly?

Comment: Do you know that MenuItems themselves can be checked? You'd allow this with `setCheckable` - in this case you'd not need to find Checkboxes, you can call `comp.setChecked(false)`

Comment: @Hawk getChildren() was indeed the key method here - thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Hawk said:

If you've created the menu item something like `menuItem.getSubMenu().addItem(new Checkbox("My option"))`, then you can iterate through the child components and deselect them:

```
menuItem.getSubMenu().getItems().forEach(subMenuItem -> {
  subMenuItem.getChildren()
      .filter(Checkbox.class::isInstance)
      .map(Checkbox.class::cast)
      .forEach(c -> c.setValue(false));
});
```

But another approach is to make the items selectable with `setCheckable(true)`. Then you would deselect them as such:

```
menuItem.getSubMenu().getItems().forEach(subMenuItem -> subMenuItem.setChecked(false));
```

There are two downsides that come to mind when using `setCheckable(true)`. First, a checkable item can not have submenus. Second, the menu will close when an item is checked.